# Is it possible to use external Fingerprint Scanner with android device/App (Closed)

Tags: android, api, save, fingerprinting, android-fingerprint-api

I want to make an android application which will use an external fingerprint scanner to get the fingerprints of the user and then save it to his/her account on the application. Is it possible to get the fingerprint Image from scanner and then save it to the android app and how?
Can please someone guide me through this? I'm not asking for code but just basics that how things work?

Comment: Got the answer.

Comment: If you got the answer then you should post it and mark it as accepted. If it's already posted then just mark it as accepted.

Comment: I was not aware of that before as I'm new here. It's done now. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Dear Adnan sheikh, Can you share you answer with me, it also urgent for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the fingerprint Image from scanner and then save it to the android app and how?

Ask the manufacturer of the fingerprint scanner if their scanner supports Android and, if so, what sort of SDK they offer.